# Removed submodule still being updated

Tags: android, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, git-submodules

I had two submodules `xxx` and `yyy`, later I removed submodule `xxx` following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211232/838355)

Still on circleci running:

```
git submodule update --init
```

I get the result:

```
Submodule 'xxx' (git@bitbucket.org:z/xxx) registered for path 'xxx'
Submodule 'yyy' (git@bitbucket.org:z/yyy) registered for path 'yyy'
Cloning into '/home/circleci/project/xxx'...
Cloning into '/home/circleci/project/yyy'...
Submodule path 'xxx': checked out 'hash**'
Submodule path 'yyy': checked out 'hash**'
```

But running :

```
git submodule
```

I see only one:

```
git submodule
 hash** yyy (heads/master)
```

the `.gitmodules` file shows only yyy

```
[submodule "yyy"]
    path = yyy
    url = git@bitbucket.org:z/yyy.git
```

the `.git/config` file though shows them both

```
[submodule "yyy"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:z/yyy.git
    active = true
[submodule "xxx"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:z/xxx.git
    active = true
```

How do I properly remove the submodule xxx

Comment: Check the modules folder inside `.git`?

Comment: You should be using `git submodule deinit`, as described in VonC's (correct) answer to that same question.